# Can we place a Frame Control inside a Tabstrip Control?

Tags: vba, userform

The below code gives me an error. Is it possible to create a Frame inside a tabstrip control? If not is there any alternative to this?

```
    Dim NewFrame As MSForms.Frame
    Dim NewTabStrip As MSForms.TabStrip
    Set NewTabStrip = Controls.Add("Forms.TabStrip.1")
    Set NewFrame = NewTabStrip.Controls.Add("Forms.TabStrip.1")
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that? A frame is essentially just a container for multiple buttons, combo-boxes, list boxes, etc. Since you have already one container (the parent form) and even a TabStrip, what would be the use of yet another form within the parent form? If you elaborate a bit more on what you want to achieve then we might be able to better assist you.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `Tab strip` is different from e.g. `Multi page` because it is not a container of controls so the code `NewTabstrip.Controls.Add...` fails. `Tab strip` doesn't have any controls but it instaed *maintains* a set of controls of the `User form`.

---

For more information see: [How to Use the TabStrip Control in a UserForm](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/155009)

And here: [How to Use the MultiPage Control in a UserForm](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/155374) are information about Multipage. It is a container for controls, page has its own controls so maybe that is what you are looking for.

---

An example how the Tabstrip control can be used to change a color of the NewFrame according to selected Tab. *(To use the example create new User form with command button named `AddTabstrip`)* HTH

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents NewTabStrip  As TabStrip
Private NewFrame As MSForms.Frame

Private Sub AddTabstrip_Click()
    If Not NewTabStrip Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Tabstrip was allready added.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set NewTabStrip = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TabStrip.1")
    With NewTabStrip
        .Height = Me.Height - 90
        .Width = Me.Width - 30
        .Top = 15
        .Left = 15
    End With
    NewTabStrip.Tabs(0).Caption = "Tab 1"
    NewTabStrip.Tabs(1).Caption = "Tab 2"
    NewTabStrip.Tabs.Add "Tab3", "Tab 3"

    Set NewFrame = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1")
    With NewFrame
        .Height = NewTabStrip.Height - 30
        .Width = NewTabStrip.Width - 30
        .Top = NewTabStrip.Top + 20
        .Left = NewTabStrip.Left + 15
    End With

    Call NewTabStripChanged
End Sub

Private Sub NewTabStrip_Change()
   Call NewTabStripChanged
End Sub

Private Sub NewTabStripChanged()
    ' This procedure runs when the TabStrip control named NewTabStrip
    ' changes. This procedure will change the color of the NewFrame
    ' control based on which tab the user selects.
    Dim i As Integer
    i = NewTabStrip.SelectedItem.Index
    Select Case i
        Case 0
            ' First tab selected, change color to red.
            NewFrame.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Case 1
            ' Second tab selected, change color to green.
            NewFrame.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        Case 2
            ' Third tab selected, change color to blue.
            NewFrame.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    End Select
End Sub
```